# Condition to check if a value exists in list containing objects,

Tags: java, list

I am trying to write an if condition to check a value exists in a list containing many objects,
Here is my code:

```
List<TeacherInfo> teacherInfo=ServiceManager.getHelperService(TeacherManagementHelper.class, request, response).getTeacherInfoId();
if(teacherInfo.contains(inputParam))
{
    out2.println("<font color=red>");
    out2.println("Id Not Available");
    out2.println("</font>");
 }
 else
 {
    out2.println("<font color=green>");
    out2.println("Id Available");
    out2.println("</font>");        
 }
```

after executing 1st sentence `getTeacherInfoId()` method successfully returns a list of objects, in those objects I want to check any object has a value same as `inputParam`. Is my above code right ? if wrong please help me .

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: `inputParam` is a integer value and objects in List contains many variables but I want to check perticularly an integer inputParam

Comment: Is `.getTeacherInfoId()` actually returning a `List<TeacherInfo>` ? This sounds wrong to me, or this is poor naming..

Comment: @Joffrey I think u r thinking about function name . , yes it realy returns a List actualy I had function by name `getTeacherInfo` so I wrote another function by adding `Id` with same name.

Comment: IMHO, `List<TeacherInfo>` should be returned by `getTeacherInfos()` and `List<Integer>` (containing ids) should be returned by `getTeacherIds()`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`contains(Object o)` is internally based on `equals` between objects of your list and your input, [as stated by the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

Since you said that `inputParam` is an *integer*, then the current state of your code can't work because you compare an integer to `TeacherInfo` objects, so they won't ever be equal. I believe you want to compare `inputParam` to one particular field of `TeacherInfo` objects.

If you're using Java 8, you can use the stream API instead of `contains()`:

```
List<TeacherInfo> teacherInfo=ServiceManager.getHelperService(TeacherManagementHelper.class, request, response).getTeacherInfoId();
if (teacherInfo.stream().anyMatch(ti -> ti.getId() == inputParam)) {
    // contains the id
} else {
    // does not contain the id
}
```

For previous java versions, an alternative to `contains()` would be to iterate over your list and compare manually your integer to the `TeacherInfo`'s field:

```
private static boolean containsTeacherId(List<TeacherInfo> teacherInfos, int id) {
    for (TeacherInfo ti : teacherInfos) {
        if (ti.getId() == inputParam) { // I used getId(), replace that by the accessor you actually need
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then:

```
List<TeacherInfo> teacherInfo=ServiceManager.getHelperService(TeacherManagementHelper.class, request, response).getTeacherInfoId();
if (containsTeacherId(teacherInfo, inputParam)) {
    // contains the id
} else {
    // does not contain the id
}
```

**Note:** If you don't need other information than the ID itself, I'd rather suggest to return the list of IDs from a method called `getTeacherIds()`, especially if this information comes from a DB.

Comment: Thanks @Joffrey , then how can I solve my pblm . . Should I override equals method?

Comment: @Raghavendra Bad idea to override equals for such a purpose. I edited my answer to give an alternative.

Comment: @Joffery Thank u very much . , I m not using Java 8 , ur so second answer is worked . . Thank u . .

Comment: @Joffrey are anyMatch/noneMatch more efficient than Collection.contains or its only for style points?

Comment: @Leon they are actually not the same thing. AnyMatch and noneMatch allow you to specify a predicate, while contain is equivalent to anyMatch with `e->e.equals(something)` as predictate

Comment: @Joffrey my apologies if my question was not clear, 
will a list.contains(e) execute slower than list.stream.anyMatch(x->x.equals(e)) or their performance is equal as well and it comes down to style in the end?

Comment: @Leon sorry I had in fact also answered the perf question, but my mobile somehow swallowed the comment. There is virtually no performance difference, although using a stream will allocate at least one more object here. But what bothers me more about the stream approach is the syntax bloat. If all you want to do is a `contains` then do this, otherwise if you have more stream operations before the `anyMatch`, use the stream approach instead

Comment: @Joffrey thanks for taking the time to answer this again. Your feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't work at all. you should iterate the 'teacherInfo' list and you need to override the compare()and hashvalue()  of object class.

Comment: why to override compare() and hashvalue()?

Comment: @Raghavendra.. you try to compare the integer value against the object values.. you need to change that and as per your requirement , no need to override the equals() and hashCode(). as you are comparing the particular int value. You should iterate over your list o objects and try to compare the respective filed.  Sorry for late response...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate over the list teacherInfo and compare each element of that list with inputParam.

Below is a small demo code that might help you.

I have created a testerInfo analogous to your teacherInfo and param analogous to your inputParam.
I hope it helps.

```
Tester.java

/**
 * 
 */
package com.demo;

/**
 * @author Parul
 *
 */
public class Tester {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Tester(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Tester() {

    }

}
```

Demo.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Parul
 *
 */
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        List<Tester> testerInfo=new ArrayList<Tester>();
        testerInfo.add(new Tester(1,"Java"));
        testerInfo.add(new Tester(2,"C++"));
        testerInfo.add(new Tester(3,"Python"));
        testerInfo.add(new Tester(4,"C"));
        Tester tester=null;
        int param=2;
        for(int i=0;i<testerInfo.size();i++){
            tester=testerInfo.get(i);
            if(tester.getId()==param){
                System.out.println("param found: "+tester.getName());
                break;
            }

        }


    }


}

OUTPUT
param found: C++
```

Comment: Thank u . . It works. I used foreach loop and my problem is solved.